# Testing a function that stores file in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

I have a function that stores a file into Sharepoint and i would like to know of any way to test it without actually trying to put anything on sharepoint. Also if someone has a better function to store files to sharepoint then i would be thankful if you can share it. 
Here's the function i have:

```
public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context, string listTitle, string fileName)
{
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            context.Load(list.RootFolder);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b5e634b-a274-4b18-a02b-7c6d4a568c78/transaction-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) seems to point toward incompatibility of TransactionScope with SharePoint.

Comment: My bad, didn't read it well I guess. Removed my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box. To know if a file has been successfully imported, it has to be successfully imported.

The only way I see to work around this issue would be to check for every detail beforehand one by one:

- Are the permissions OK?
- Do the new item's column values follow the validation rules?
- Are every column value in the right data type?

etc... Pretty annoying, if you ask me. The simplest way is still to use a test version of your site (see [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49d22f46-b2bf-4046-8aa3-03a9e110f4bc/is-it-possible-to-export-a-site-or-sitecollection-without-content?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) on how to copy a site's structure).

Talking about columns, you don't seem to have any, so SaveBinaryDirect works. If you want to set columns values though, you will have to do it in two steps, like this:

```
// Upload
FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
fileInfo.Content = IOFile.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
fileInfo.Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = rootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

// Columns setting
ListItem listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["Field1"] = "foo";
listItem["Field2"] = "bar";
listItem.Update();

// Execution
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

---

Edit: @RandomStranger pointed out TransactionScope. It doesn't seem to work with SharePoint out of the box, but [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b5e634b-a274-4b18-a02b-7c6d4a568c78/transaction-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) provides insight on how to work around it (creating your own transaction manager, or even using lists versioning).

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the only way to go then.